# Reset php server browser cookies

Tags: php, html, file, cookies, get

I'm using file_get_html to scrape a website but if I made a lot of request I get "banned" and if I want to regain access I need to click on some anti-bot thing and it will unlock the site but just for the browser/pc where I do this. My question is there any way to unblock the php browser(maybe copy cookies from another browser?) without rebooting the router(to get another ip adress).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ***ANSWER FOR ORIGINAL QUESTION:***

I did have a solution which I've researched before.
Though it's not that 100% legitimate. However the action you're doing is also not very legit....So I think it might be fine.

Also the anti-bot they blocks you based on the IP, clearing the cookie does nothing to bypass. You will still get the captcha page even you cleared the cookie.

First you know that the anti-bot site gives google-recaptcha right?

So you can make a javascript to detect the google-recaptcha div(my case I use jQuery), if gcaptcha div detected then use a third-party captcha solving API. In my case I use [2captcha](http://2captcha.com) --> send them captcha id with your own proxy(for gcaptcha a proxy is necessary, you can host a proxy with squid proxy server) --> then they send you a g-response --> you post the g-response back to the site --> unblock

The price is very-very-very cheap, for me is affordable so I treat this as a good solution.

I can't post you my script due to restrictions, however you can find some example on their website.

### ***NEW EDIT : FOR YOUR SECOND QUESTION ASKED IN COMMENT:***

> YOUR QUESTION:
> So basically from what I understand I can get that captcha-id(send to
> myself) and solve it (like 2captcha.com people) then scrape script
> will work again. I think it's just basic php and html to do this, if
> you have any hints I'm glad to hear. Thank you!

To achieve this, I suggest you open any login page which has recaptcha with browser's built-in developer tool, inspect a little bit before writing any code. Personally I use Opera Browser....

1. Open a login page with browser which has recaptcha
2. Browser->right click->Inspect elements->Open Network Tab
3. Now check the checkbox "I am not a robot", you'll see two HTTP POST
   have been done, find the one with the URL
   https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/userverify?k=SITE_KEY_HERE ,
   look at the response part, you'll see google responded you a json
   object, something like {"uvresp":"A_LONG_STRING_HERE_blablablabla",
   ,} A_LONG_STRING_HERE_blablablabla is exactly what we need
4. Now you enter anything at login and password, press login and look
   at the network again, you'll find not only username and password, a pair of value also being POSTed to
   server, which is
   `g-recaptcha-response=A_LONG_STRING_HERE_blablablabla`. So whenever
   a recaptcha appears, post g-recaptcha-response will pass the
   verification.

***Now here's some suggestions to your code.***

*for php server side:*

After using file_get_html, detect some `<div>` in recaptcha, such as `<div class="rc-anchor-content">`. if captcha detected, stop any scraping and wait for an answer, display a page with an input parameter which you're going to input `g-recaptcha-response`and a submit button.

note: If you try to copy all the elements of `<div class="g-recaptcha">` and display it on your website, you might get an "site-key" wrong error, because the captcha itself also detects where was it displayed from(url). However you might be able to trick it if you use some javascript?(or you can try the none javascript version of recaptcha?disable javascript and you'll see one, not sure how it works) 2captcha.com might have done this because I've seen a recaptcha displayed on their worker page before, you can go register a worker account and inspect their worker page.

*for what you need to do on desktop:*

Open target website with normal browser(must have the same ip with php browser, can use proxy), click on the checkbox then copy the json response from google. submit this string to your php server, remember a g-response session only valid in 3-5 minutes,it will expire.

*back to php browser:*

php server received your g-recaptcha-response srting, POST it to target website(dont forget other post values(if exist)), unblock

Comment: I'm just getting some product prices, It's nothing fancy, your method seems good but too much work for that, I think I will add some sleep time and everything will be ok if I don't find another method.

Comment: Can I somehow use php browser to manually clear that captcha ? Like I do on a normal browser but instead do it on the php side browser.

Comment: `Can I somehow use php browser to manually clear that captcha ?` Remember captcha is an anti-bot solution, it's designed to prevent you scraping any data from an extraordinary browser. Yes, there did have libraries let you solve captcha with codes but that depends on the type of the captcha. Traditional captcha were images made with English vocabularies(powerd by GD library), most of them are readable with a lot of open source libraries on github, such as, [this library](https://github.com/ptigas/simple-captcha-solver)

Comment: However the newest captcha technology invented by google which is still not readable with any library. It asks you to pick the picture with car or a shop or something, no one has found a solution to it. There do exist [a library](https://github.com/eastee/rebreakcaptcha) can bypass google recaptcha v2, but it does't read the captcha, it uses captcha's exploit instead. Any solution with a exploit hack can not be treated as a long-time working solution. The only stable solution with google recaptcha v2 is to use a human powerd captcha solver to do it for you, they hire real people read it.

Comment: Let me explain how human based captcha solver works. First your php browser requested data form a website, website recorded your ip(example ip 110.20.30.40) and send your ip to google, google determines which type of captcha should it send to you based on your ip, then google generate the captcha items to you and you see the captcha item in the html. Now you send captcha-id to such as 2captcha.com, their people connects your proxy(which has the same ip with your php browser 110.20.30.40) and the real people read the captcha, they have the answer. You request the answer from 2captcha.com

Comment: Now you have the captcha answer, you use HTTP POST send the answer to the website, the website then send your answer to google and validate your answer, if google mark you answer validated, then you're passed otherwise your're blocked.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't ask my second question correctly, my problem is that I get this captcha like one or two times a day, I have time to solve it but I don't know how to solve it without having it in a "physical" browser like chrome/ie. So basically from what I understand I can get that captcha-id(send to myself) and solve it (like 2captcha.com people) then scrape script will work again. I think it's just basic php and html to do this, if you have any hints I'm glad to hear. Thank you!